# How to uninstall android app using react native

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, kotlin, uninstallation

I know how to get app list using react, but I don't know how to uninstall these apps using react. Which way should I look for this issue? Delete from data/app, but this requires root rights. Any way around this? How android app uninstaller works?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On clicking a button in my application, another application should be deleted. I need ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE